# How to timeout with Socket.gethostbyaddr()?

Tags: ruby

How to timeout with Socket.gethostbyaddr() like below code?

```rb
begin
  addr = ip_address.split('.').map {|x| x.to_i}.pack('C4')
  return Socket.gethostbyaddr(addr).first
rescue SocketError
  return ip_address
end
```

`Timeout::timeout()` can't interrupt C level implementations.

Comment: Try using [Resolv](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html) instead of that method if you want more control over timeouts.

Comment: Great! I solved problem.

Comment: If you've got a working solution you want to share, add the working code as an answer to your own question. You never know, you might forget and need to find this later, a chance for your future self to thank your past self.